# How to pass vars from AIR App to external SWF

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, air

I am developing an air application where I have to drop an image and save the Image path, width, height to variables and pass those variables to external swf. I load the swf like this:

```
var myLoader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();  
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myExternalMovie.swf");
myLoader.load(url);
```

I am getting this error: the way I am passing the URL of the swf is incorrect and not supported in AIR.

Comment: Is there a reason why do you have to save this variable to an SWF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't encountered this one myself yet but, the first thing that came to mind is well what path should that be.  That is if I look at some filename from an application am I concerned with a path relative to the application's current working directory from which it was executed or am I concerned with the application install folder and paths relative to there, looking at the docs it seems Adobe went down the same line of thought and provided the ability (and need) to specify:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=url_requests_2.html#1030295

Was going to copy but basically read through the section titled

Using AIR URL schemes in URLs